# How do you get the image from gatsby component using posts not data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I wanted customize the Gatsby NetlifyCMS template.  I'm really new with Gatsby.

I wanted to get the "social_image" from the markdown file and put it on the blog post-list in the main page, but the image doesn't show on the website after deployment.

This is the starter website I'm using "https://gatsbyglass.netlify.app/".

and this is the code.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import Tags from "./tags";


const PostList = ({ posts }) => {

  const PostList = posts.map(({ frontmatter, fields, excerpt, timeToRead }) => {
    const { title, tags, date, description, social_image } = frontmatter;
    const { slug } = fields;
  
    return (
      <PostListItem
        key={slug}
        tags={tags}
        title={title}
        date={date}
        slug={slug}
        timeToRead={timeToRead}
        description={description}
        social_image={social_image}
        excerpt={excerpt}
      />
    );
  });

  return <StyledPostList>{PostList}</StyledPostList>;
};

export default PostList;

const PostListItem = ({
  title,
  date,
  timeToRead,
  tags,
  excerpt,
  description,
  slug,
  social_image
}) => {
  return (
    <StyledPostListItem>
      <ImageWrapper>
        <div>{social_image}</div>
      </ImageWrapper>
      <PostListTitle>
        <Link to={slug}>{title}</Link>
      </PostListTitle>
      <PostListExcerpt
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: description || excerpt,
        }}
      />
      <Tags tags={tags} />
      <PostListMeta>
        <span>{date}</span>

        <span>{timeToRead} mins</span>
      </PostListMeta>
    </StyledPostListItem>
  );
};

const ImageWrapper = styled.div`
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
`;

const StyledPostList = styled.ul`
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-gap: var(--size-600);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(35ch, 1fr));

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    & {
      display: block;
    }
  }
`;

const StyledPostListItem = styled.li`
  display: flex;
  
  
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;

  body.light-mode & {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  }

  body.light-mode &:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }

  body.dark-mode & {
    background-color: #3b3b3c;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    & {
      margin-top: var(--size-600);
    }
  }
`;

const PostListTitle = styled.h2`
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: var(--size-600);
  font-weight: 700;

  & a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
  }

  & a::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
`;

const PostListExcerpt = styled.p`
  margin-top: auto;
  font-size: var(--size-400);
`;

const PostListMeta = styled.div`
  margin-top: 2rem;

  font-size: var(--size-300);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;
```

Comment: Where's the query? Are you getting `social_image` from there? Is the markdown containing the `social_image` field?

Comment: So this is code from "src/components" folder so I guess it didn't use the graphql.  Instead of "Data" this template pulled the data from "posts" which I'm not sure how it exactly works.  Here's the github "https://github.com/yinkakun/gatsby-starter-glass"  Maybe you can point me into right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have a messy structure and repeated code, passing some props through Layout context and some others don't, however, I guess the issue is the [`Blog` component](https://github.com/yinkakun/gatsby-starter-glass/blob/e15c31d304d28b55516dce196e6f4a9d285dadb6/src/pages/blog.js#L45), where you are not fetching the full markdown signature of the post. Change it to:

```
// should be named blogPageQuery? 
export const homePageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    allMarkdownRemark(
      filter: { fields: { contentType: { eq: "posts" } } }
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: frontmatter___date }
    ) {
      nodes {
        fields {
          slug
        }
        excerpt
        timeToRead
        frontmatter {
          date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          description
          title
          tags
          social_image # <-- here
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Then, your posts should automatically get the `social_image` field since you are already passing the data:

```
<PostList posts={posts} />
```